# How to get power charts and reports for tfs

Tags: tfs

I want to get some different reports and charts from Tfs activities and history (most based on task tags and assigned users). for example after 3 monthes I want to know how many hours a user moved her tasks to next iteration, ...
Is there any tools for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such a tool can exactly achieve that. There is an extension [Team Capacity Management](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tfc.team-capacity), but seems it's not apply for you.

If you want to know how many hours a user moved her tasks to next iteration, then you need to get the planned hours then subtract the completed hours in current iteration. Alternatively you can add tags on the work items which moved to the next  iteration, then create a query which filter by the tags to get the sum of hours.

e.g.:

1. Create a query '**RemainingWork**' with the column `Assigned
   to` and `Remaining Work` added in "next iteration" (e.g.: iteration
   2 here) to filter the moved work items from pervious iteration with the tag.
2. Save it in **Shared queries**
3. Add **Chart for Work items** widget in your project dashborad, then
   configure the widget. Then you can see the hours a user moved tasks
   to next iteration in the chart:

[image]